# Use logging print the output of pprint

Tags: python, logging, python-logging, pprint

I want to use pprint's output to show a complex data structure, but I would like to output it using the logging module rather than stdout.

```
ds = [{'hello': 'there'}]
logging.debug( pprint.pprint(ds) ) # outputs as STDOUT
```

Comment: i glanced through the docs and found `pprint( {}, stream )`, but found it rather awkward. i would have thought something like `spprint` might have been nicer than `pformat` (like in `c`).

Comment: `pprint.pformat()` was on that page.

Comment: @Lattywayre - Not everyone who asks a question like this has skipped the docs. I read the same docs and also missed pformat. On stackoverflow you also sometimes get gems from other people's experience that weren't in the docs at all. Thanks yee379 for asking this.

Answer (score 319, accepted):

Use [`pprint.pformat`](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html#pprint.pformat) to get a string, and then send it to your logging framework.

```
from pprint import pformat
ds = [{'hello': 'there'}]
logging.debug(pformat(ds))
```

Comment: If you don't remove this code after you're done debugging, you should probably guard it with "if Logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):" to avoid running pformat when you won't use its output: http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.isEnabledFor

Comment: @EdBrannin Does pformat add that much overhead that it's worth the trouble of adding the conditionals to all the DEBUG log statements?

Comment: @undefinedvariable Good question.  Me-today wants to tell Me-2-years-ago to generate some A/B performance metrics.

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'pformat'` any idea why?

Comment: solution: I needed `from pprint import pprint,pformat`  then `logging.debug((pformat(stuff))`

Comment: I believe if you use `logging.debug("%s", pformat(ds))` you should avoid the overhead of `pformat` when the `logLevel` is > `DEBUG`. Here is a [link](https://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2015/06/05/logging-formatting.html) to good info on string formatting for logging.

Comment: I was hoping you are right RoHS4U but I can't find any evidence in that link, the docs or anywhere else.

Comment: {'general': 'kenobi'}

Comment: `logging.debug("%s", pformat(ds))` won't avoid the `pformat` call. That format simply means that, if debug logging is disabled, then a new string won't be created by formatting the template string with the other arguments. The arguments themselves, if results of a function call, **will** be evaluated.

Answer (score 25):

The solution above didn't *quite* cut it for me because I'm also using a formatter to add name and levelname when logging. It looks a little untidy:

```
__main__    : DEBUG   : ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb',
'cccccccccccccccccccc',
'dddddddddddddddddddd']
__main__    : DEBUG   : Some other logging text
```

There may be a more elegant solution, but this:

```
for line in pprint.pformat(ds).split('\n'):
    logging.debug(line)
```

produces something a little nicer:

```
__main__    : DEBUG   : ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
__main__    : DEBUG   :  'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb',
__main__    : DEBUG   :  'cccccccccccccccccccc',
__main__    : DEBUG   :  'dddddddddddddddddddd']
__main__    : DEBUG   : Some other logging text
```

Comment: Nicer for human consumption. Not so great if you're shipping logs to logstash or similar tools, and want a single multiline message to be sent as, well, one message.

Comment: is there a way to pretty print at the handler/formatter level of the logger config? Seems like a valid use case to pretty print to console, but go unformatted to file

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Is there any easy way to handle both cases?

Comment: Fwiw my solution has been to just add an extra `\n` character in the pformat. At least this way the block is together.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think the proper solution would be to fix the default Python console logging handler, so knows about `pformat()` and prefixes every line in the output with the configured logger format.

Answer (score 11):

An alternative is to use `json.dumps` with the `indent` arg. In some cases (depending on logging format, data size, etc) it might give you nicer output.

```
logging.error('Malformed input data!')
logging.error(pformat(foo))

ERROR:root:Malformed input data!
ERROR:root:{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 'womp rat', 'd': 'turd sandwich'}
```

vs.

```
logging.error('Malformed input data!') 
logging.error(json.dumps(foo, indent=4))

ERROR:root:Malformed input data!
ERROR:root:{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": "womp rat",
    "d": "turd sandwich"
}
```

Comment: I thought this gave a nicer output than the accepted answer. +1!

Comment: Does not ATQ since it does not use pprint, but is a better general soln.  May wish to prepend the dumps() with a `\n`.